# Determine if collection of elements are visible using JQuery like $(".someClass")

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a collection of elements on my page, and I want to see if they are visible or not currently.

So:

```
$(".someClass")
```

How can I loop through and figure this out? because if it is visible, i have to fire another function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(".someClass").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(":visible")){
    //item is visible: do something
   }
});
```

how about that?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure this is exactly what he's looking for

Comment: $('.someClass:visible').each(function(){
  // item is visible, do something
}

Would that not be more optimized?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".someClass:visible")
```

will return the visible ones.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do:

```
$(".someClass").each(function(x) { if ( x.style.display != "none" && x.style.visibility != "hidden" ) { your_function(); } });
```

where `your_function()` is the name of your function.

Answer (score 1):

All solutions in terms of `$('.someClass').is(':visible')` are unreliable. All it tells us is if a particular element has a styling of `display:none` or `visibility:hidden`. This is **not** the same as whether an element is visible!

Consider a situation like this:

> `<div style="display:none;"><div class="someClass"></div></div>`

Everybody can see that the element designated by `$('.someClass')` is invisible. But `$('.someClass').is(':visible')` will return `true`!

The only water-proof solution is to not only check for `is(':visible')` on the `$('.someClass')`, but on all of its parent elements as well. Only if for **none** of the parents holds that `is(':visible') === false`, we can conclude that `$('.someClass')` is actually visible.

Comment: Actually, they've overhauled the logic of :visible and :hidden selectors in version 1.3.2 to account for this case: http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3.2#:visible.2F:hidden_Overhauled